# Can we stop upvoting duplicates about the rep recalc and their answers?

Tags: discussion, meta, reputation-recalc

I don't really understand how storming to meta without taking a second to read the front page or the notification bar is a behavior we want to encourage. Why have <s>almost</s> all of those questions been upvoted at least once?

And, especially, why are some people answering them anyway even if they are fully aware that they are duplicates?

Comment: I'm guessing the upvotes come from before the question is migrated

Comment: @Farseeker: very very few questions have been migrated (you are notified if they are)

Comment: I have downvoted almost every one of them. This has cost me about 20 rep points. Why?! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Must... Click ..... Up arrow....

It *calls to me!*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I totally agree

Upvote this answer instead!

Comment: Done. Now where's my rep?

Comment: It's in the mail

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps people are trying to up their downvote:upvote ratio to avoid [item-the-second](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/)

Answer (score 1):

By the same token, they shouldn't be downvoted either. If someone is feeling bad about the situation, there's no need to make it worse.

(I'm not blaming anyone, I'm just saying. The downvotes could have come from before a migration, too. A bunch of the dupes just got deleted before I had a chance to look at them.)